# I am executing mutistatement queries, but I am unable to fetch the result for each query

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, google-bigquery

```
  const options = {
        query: `
             SELECT * from ENVIRONMENTAL__WASTE where ROWID = '1';
             SELECT * from ENVIRONMENTAL__WASTE where ROWID = '2';
        `,
        location: 'EU',
      };
  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  const [rows] = await job.getQueryResults();
```

I am only getting result of last query with this job.getQueryResults().
How to get result for each query?

I am using BigQuery in node.js

Comment: You can simply use `SELECT * from ENVIRONMENTAL__WASTE where ROWID IN('1', '2')` instead ?

Comment: That was just an example, I wanted to perform queries inside a transaction originally, and I was not able to do that

Answer (score 0):

```
 let query= `SELECT * from ENVIRONMENTAL__WASTE where ROWID IN('1','2')`;
 
  const [rows] = await.getQueryResults(query);
```

**you can use this for multiple results or use as a variable**

```
 let query= `SELECT * from ENVIRONMENTAL__WASTE where ${condition};
   
  let array =[1,2,3,4]

  let condition = ROWID IN(array)`

  const [rows] = await.getQueryResults(query);
```